# How to get the cid in the Google Place URL?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I want to send a request to the google places (not google place API), I don't need to get the data in XML or JSON, i just want to get the place page and display it to the user.

This url works for me http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=2124238351431937390 but I was wondering how to get this "cid", this seems to a unique id for a business. I went to get a sample response from the google place api but didnt find this cid for the same business as any of the response fields.

Does anyone know how can I get this "cid"?

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to get the cid of a place. Put your own API key and name of the restaurant that you want to find the cid).

**Step 1: Call Places Request API something like this**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?
    location=47.6757453,-122.3149514&
    radius=500&
    types=food&
    name=Pies&
    sensor=false&
    key=AIzaSyZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

<sub>These urls are one line. They are broken into multiple lines to make it easier to read.</sub>

Note the `name` parameter is the restaurant called "Pies and Pints" for which I want to get the cid, lat&lng is the location information of the same place.

The response will contain a "reference" key which is unique for every place.

**Step 2: Take the "reference" value from above and call Places Details API, something like this:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?
    reference=CnRiAAAATIbN_GasBkBS6xLoO_HzR7owHvGaDXbG5QIbLf7eSZtIc4ZpvbBPxhVPEKZs5c4ptqxeKNVLCXZEoSOwLMn9nqkRc6khFuJFPh5jy-hjrh3Xr7X75w3-TIoTl3E-dKiZ2LcHuReWKZxydI75vH6zyRIQxfoiOKfFjo_1O-hnnllafxoU9tU_HoZos8C5uWextAk08RMukCY&
    sensor=true&
    key=AIzaSyBnI5DyG7ZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Check the response of this API, the key "url" contains the "cid".

---

Consult the google places documentation to learn more about their APIs.

Comment: I need something harder than beer after that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the URL no longer contains the CID but rather the plus.google.com link

Answer (score 0):

To get the CID in Google Maps Places Details API you just pass the URL value in the fields parameter. This will get you the URL of the particular location and there you can find the CID.

```
"url": "https://maps.google.com/?cid=12XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```