# Is there a way to obtain a JSON about a POI with its CID?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As stated in the question, I have the CID of a place in gmaps, and I now want to get a JSON containing the information about it.

I read up on the gmaps documentation, but I couldn't find any suitable example on how to do it like this, besides one which would give me results based on latitude and longitude.

Is there any way to grab a JSON with just providing the CID, which I think is an unique identifiert for a POI?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the ID format I currently have (CID):

```
8266932037173600175
```

And this is an example for what I'm looking to get (place_id):

```
ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk
```

Both are actually different, while only the place_id is a legit parameter to obtain a POI JSON, while the CID does not seem to be a possibility for this query.

EDIT2:

This is where I got the CID from:

[image]

->

[image]

Comment: Where does the CID come from?

Comment: @geocodezip I found it in the HTML structure of the window which pops up when I click on an POI. I'll add a picture for it. It is embedded in the <a> element.

Comment: related question: [How to get the cid in the google place url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989930/how-to-get-the-cid-in-the-google-place-url) (looks like cid is from the "old" google maps).

Comment: @geocodezip Yes it is, according to that question OP wants to only achieve to get a link to the place, however, I want the different, which would be the JSON. He also seems to be searching for the CID

Answer (score 0):

Given a `placeId` like this one (from the [PlaceId Finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)):

```
Statue of Liberty National Monument
Place ID: ChIJPTacEpBQwokRKwIlDXelxkA
New York, NY, United States
```

You can call the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) [Details Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details):

> The following example requests the details of a place by placeid:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJPTacEpBQwokRKwIlDXelxkA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

> Note that you'll need to replace the key in this example with your own API key in order for the request to work in your application.

Comment: Is there a way to programatically obtain the place_Id?

Comment: Is that not the CID you have?  If not, please add details to your question about what you are looking for.